# Manipulating output return from az cli command in powershell or azcli

Tags: azure, powershell

I ran the following AZ cli command below, whilst it provided me with the information I was after, I could not filter or select the columns I wanted.

```
az pipelines list --org org_url --project az_project --out table
```

I am after the name and status column only, and would like to filter on where the name matches the string "dev"

Another option i looked at was piping this out in Powershell

```
$output =     az pipelines list --org org_url --project az_project --out table   
$output | select-object name, status
```

I found that this didnt work either, as looking at the members of $output suggests it was not converted to a custom object. I am thinking there must be a way to do this in powershell.

Comment: You could try `az pipelines list --org org_url --project az_project | ConvertFrom-Json -Depth 10 | Select Name,Status`.

Comment: Thanks @AdminOfThings that did work. I cannot seem to propose your comments as an answer. But I will reply and mention you as the provider of the answer

Answer (score 5):

Credit to @AdminOfThings
This is what I was trying to do.

```
az pipelines list --org org_url --project az_project | ConvertFrom-Json -Depth 10 | Select Name,Status  | where {$_.Name -like "*name*"}
```